# Difficulty setting variable

Tags: java, class, variables, methods

I'm supposed to write a code for my programming class that will act as though you are ordering something online. I've reached the part where I have the program take the item number put in and return a price (without shipping costs), but every time I run it, it seems to have automatically set the variable I'm using to represent price to 13. It should be set to zero.
Here's the part of my code that's giving me issues:

```
class Order {
    public Order() {}

    public double price(String odd, double quant, int g) {
        double set;
        if (g == 1) {
            if (odd.equals("AT413")) {
                set = (50.03 * quant) + set;
            } else if (odd.equals("AT414")) {
                set = (60.04 * quant) + set;
            } else if (odd.equals("AT415")) {
                set = (147.01 * quant) + set;
            } else if (odd.equals("AT416")) {
                set = (38.00 * quant) + set;
            } else if (odd.equals("AT417")); {
                set = (13.00 * quant) + set;
            }
        } else if (g == 2) {
            if (odd.equals("AT513")) {
                set = (50.03 * quant) + set;
            } else if (odd.equals("AT514")) {
                set = (50.00 * quant) + set;
            } else if (odd.equals("AT515")) {
                set = (130.02 * quant) + set;
            } else if (odd.equals("AT516")) {
                set = (25.03 * quant) + set;
            } else if (odd.equals("AT517")); {
                set = (13.00 * quant) + set;
            }
        } else if (g == 3) {
            if (odd.equals("AT613")) {
                set = (50.03 * quant) + set;
            } else if (odd.equals("AT614")) {
                set = (86.00 * quant) + set;
            } else if (odd.equals("AT615")) {
                set = (130.00 * quant) + set;
            } else if (odd.equals("AT616")) {
                set = (40.04 * quant) + set;
            } else if (odd.equals("AT617")); {
                set = (13.00 * quant) + set;
            }
        }
        return set;
    }
}
```

I tried a few different things. I had it get the variable set from the main code, but that didn't work because even if I sent down 0 to the class, it still set...set (sorry about that variable name) at 13. I tried getting rid of the +set at the end, but that didn't work because then it just printed out 13 as the order cost, even if I put in the String that's supposed to call up 50.03 for the price. I changed matching prices to see what would happen, and I realized that it's pulling the number it's set the variable at from very last line of code, with AT617, but I don't know why it's doing that or how to fix it. Help would be much appreciated, please.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could format all those if statements... please.

Comment: it's that semicolon on the  `else if(odd.equals("AT417"));` line

Comment: That if statement is an abomination :( Please format it better. Also consider using Enumerations or something to old your literals.

Comment: Not sure how you caught that Gus, but nice one!

Comment: Note that you still might end up not initializing `set` because those inner blocks still don't have a final unconditional `else`.  What happens when, e.g., `g` is `3`, but `odd` doesn't equal AT613, AT614, AT615, AT616, or AT617?

Comment: Why have you done something like: `set = (40.04 * quant) + set;`? If `set`'s default value is `0`, then why shall you add with it?

Comment: It won't compile at all, because you have not initialized set and used its value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you had formatted your code you could have seen that

```
public double price(String odd, double quant, int g) {
    double set = 0;
    if (g == 1) {
        if (odd.equals("AT413"))
            set = 50.03 * quant + set;
        else if (odd.equals("AT414"))
            set = 60.04 * quant + set;
        else if (odd.equals("AT415"))
            set = 147.01 * quant + set;
        else if (odd.equals("AT416"))
            set = 38.00 * quant + set;
        else if (odd.equals("AT417"))
            ;
        {
            set = 13.00 * quant + set;
        }
    } else if (g == 2) {
        if (odd.equals("AT513"))
            set = 50.03 * quant + set;
        else if (odd.equals("AT514"))
            set = 50.00 * quant + set;
        else if (odd.equals("AT515"))
            set = 130.02 * quant + set;
        else if (odd.equals("AT516"))
            set = 25.03 * quant + set;
        else if (odd.equals("AT517"))
            ;
        {
            set = 13.00 * quant + set;
        }
    } else if (g == 3) {
        if (odd.equals("AT613"))
            set = 50.03 * quant + set;
        else if (odd.equals("AT614"))
            set = 86.00 * quant + set;
        else if (odd.equals("AT615"))
            set = 130.00 * quant + set;
        else if (odd.equals("AT616"))
            set = 40.04 * quant + set;
        else if (odd.equals("AT617"))
            ;
        {
            set = 13.00 * quant + set;
        }
    }
    return set;
}
```

has very strange looking pieces like

```
        else if (odd.equals("AT417"))
            ;
        {
            set = 13.00 * quant + set;
        }
```

Remove that semicolon or the `if (odd.equals("AT417"))` case executes an empty statement, and any case the unnecessarily {} enclosed `set = 13.00 * quant + set;` which will mess up all your results.

Answer (score 1):

I really recommend formatting the code.

```
else if(odd.equals("AT517"));
```

Has a ;

So does

```
else if(odd.equals("AT617"));
```

Comment: Sorry about the non-formatted code, I thought I had it but apparently not. It's formatted right on my computer, can't believe I missed that...thanks for your help!

Comment: A tip is to use a text editor that allows multi-tab (selecting all code and add an extra tab before you paste it here, as it is required 4 spaces or a tab to be properly indented here.

Comment: @user2808951 or use eclipse, that has a warning specifically for ; after ifs